# Turn off "on the fly" reformatting of code in IPython REPL

Tags: python, ipython, read-eval-print-loop

Starting with IPython 8.0, the code I type in the REPL is reformatted automagically.

As it happens (and I realize it's my fault), I am confused by this behavior. If I had the choice between getting accustomed to this new experience and turning it off, I'd choose option no. 2.

How can I turn off the "on the fly" reformatting in IPython 8.0?

Comment: Sounds like `%autoindent`, but that's older than IPython 8.0.

Comment: Ah, [here's](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version8.html#auto-formatting-with-black-in-the-cli) the new feature (and the toggle to turn it off).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica `TerminalInteractiveShell.autoformatter=None` is probably leading in the right direction, but must it be in a configuration file, must it be specified on the command line, have I to import a module to have it work...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython supports a couple configuration methods, with profiles being the most common.
You can create the default profile configuration file by running `ipython profile create` which will create a `ipython_config.py` file under `.ipython` in your home dir.

In there you can find a commented entry for

```py
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.autoformatter = None
```

either uncomment this, or set it to None yourself and black will no longer be automatically applied to the code.

If modifying the profile's config is not viable the other options are documented [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html?highlight=Json#python-configuration-files).

Comment: I'll probably use the command line format of the configuration, and a convenient alias so that I can choose the behavior when I start the REPL. Thank you very much for the clarification.